# Pascal memory issues

Tags: freepascal

I have a problem that requires searching and saving some values that prevent it from doing an infinite loop. Every possible state of this problem is expressed as an unique 8 digit code with base 6 (all digits are 0-5). When the program evaluates this position, I want a boolean to be set as true so as not to evaluate this position again. However an array 1..55555555 is too large in memory and if i convert the 8 digit code to decimal it takes too much time. Also not all combinations are possible in the problem; 11 11 11 11,  11 11 55 12 and others are not valid and i need not use extra memory. So, is there a way to store as value "true" a block of memory with adress e.g 23451211 and when i call the evaluating process check if 23451211 is true or unassigned;

Comment: Could you post your code or parts of it? That would help.

Answer (score 2):

6 to the power 8 = 1679616.

To mark used or not you need one bit, thus you can do with about 209952 bytes.

In recent Free Pascal's, bitpacked structures are done as follows

```
      var
          arr : bitpacked array [0..6*6*6*6*6*6*6*6-1] of boolean;
```

and arr[x] will give true or false.

The conversion time from base 6 to binary (not decimal!) will probably be shorter than trying to use large swaths of memory.  `(((digit8)*6+digit7)*6+digit6)*6`   etc

p.s. FPC does have an exponent operator, but not for constants, so that's why 6^8 is written like that.